# How to avoid html code from data result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm getting some data using php json, well the result bring me the html code too, so the page is giving me a unexpected token. Here my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function(){
        loadData();
    });

    var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Users.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i in users){
                $("#content").append(users[i].nombre + " " + users[i].apellido + "<br>");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and this is what I see in the console

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

[{"nombre":"Joelbis","apellido":"Rosas"},{"nombre":"William","apellido":"Mazo"},{"nombre":"Mariana","apellido":"De Barros"},{"nombre":"Daniela","apellido":"Ramirez"}]


</body>
</html>
VM396:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(anonymous function) @ userview.php:22l @ jquery.min.js:4c.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4k @ jquery.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:6
```

How I avoid the html code in the result?

Thank you.

Comment: somethings wrong in the php code then. You've posted the wrong part of the problem

Comment: <?php echo '[{"nombre":"Joelbis","apellido":"Rosas"},{"nombre":"William","apellido":"Mazo"},{"nombre":"Mariana","apellido":"De Barros"},{"nombre":"Daniela","apellido":"Ramirez"}]';

Comment: Ajax will always bring back everything that's displayed on the requested url. If you only want your users JSON back you should have a PHP web service that only echoes that.

Comment: but that `echo` is mixed into some html somehow... there should be nothing coming out of that php except that one echo

Comment: Users.php is outputting the HTML.  Is this a framework or CMS?

Comment: Fer Salas, so, it's something about the server settings?

Comment: Not a server setting, a problem in `Users.php`. When it's being used for AJAX, it shouldn't output any HTML, the only thing it should output is `echo json_encode($whatever)`.

Comment: @William Post the contents of `Users.php`.

Comment: charlietfl, here the php code from the other file

    $sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM pruebaUsuarios";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$array_user = array();
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $array_user[] = $data;
}

    echo json_encode($array_user);

Comment: @William No it's not the server settings. What you need is a php file that only prints out the JSON data you want. If your php file has more content printed it will return everything that's on the page.

Comment: Well, I checked the file User.php and it has that html lines, that was the problem, as you told me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a php file that ONLY prints out the data you need returned. Like this:

Ajax Call

```
var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"UserData.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i in users){
                $("#content").append(users[i].nombre + " " + users[i].apellido + "<br>");
            }
        });
    }
```

UserData.php

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM pruebaUsuarios"; $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 

  $array_user = array(); while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ $array_user[] = $data; } 

  echo json_encode($array_user)
?>
```

Comment: I checked the file User.php and it has that html lines, that was the problem, as you told me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your backend script must stop right after `echo json_encode($data)`, using `die()` or `exit()` which are the same. Otherwise it will feed the rest of your page to your AJAX frontend, which is what's currently happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Users.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            data = $(data).find('body').html();
            var users = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i in users){
                $("#content").append(users[i].nombre + " " + users[i].apellido + "<br>");
            }
        });
    }
```

Try to parse data from html